# how to add attribute in json object?

Tags: json

**I want to add attribute( status:0) in object like:-**

```
{id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"}
{id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime",status:0}
```

Comment: That's how you do it in JSON but I assume your question has another scope than the topic implies?

Comment: {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime", status: "0"}

Comment: i want to add status attribute in json object -: {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"}

Comment: That isn't JSON. In JSON all property names are strings (not identifiers) which means they must be quoted. To edit it, open it in a text editor and start typing (or pick a programming language with a JSON parser, use that to turn it into a native object, manipulate it in the usual way for the langage you selected, then spit it out through a JSON serializer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about doing this in Java. You can do it with [JSONObject.put(String, int)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use put method.

```
var obj;
obj.put(status,0);
```

or

```
obj['status']=0;
```

or

```
obj.status=0;
```